# Is it possible to create a code that exports/prints entire pages that contain a keyword from a word file

Tags: ms-word

I have a word document that is nearly 2000 pages long and I need to print out/extract only pages that contain a specific word, its already possible to isolate the pages using the find function but is there a script that can somehow either extract those page numbers automatically or just outright extract the pages themselves, im still new to coding so i can't figure out where to even start on this one. thanks

-didnt really try anything since idek how to go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Try the following macro. It both prints the document and generates an equivalent PDF with the same name as the document, in the document's own folder. You can comment-out/delete either the .Printout or .SaveAs line if you don't require a given output.

```
Sub ConditionalPrint()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim bOpt As Boolean, Rng As Range
'Configure Word to NOT print hidden text
bOpt = Options.PrintHiddenText
Options.PrintHiddenText = False
'create & deploy a custom UndoRecord, so we can roll back all our actions at the end
Dim objUndo As UndoRecord: Set objUndo = Application.UndoRecord: objUndo.StartCustomRecord ("CustomPrint")
With ActiveDocument
  .ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True
  With .Range
    .Font.Hidden = True
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = InputBox("What is the Text to Find on the Pages to be Printed")
      .Font.Hidden = True
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute
      Set Rng = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)).GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
      Rng.Font.Hidden = False
      .Start = Rng.End
    Loop
  End With
  .Fields.Update
  .PrintPreview
  .ClosePrintPreview
  .PrintOut
  .SaveAs FileName:=Split(.FullName, ".doc")(0) & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
End With
'Terminate our custom UndoRecord & roll back all our actions
objUndo.EndCustomRecord: ActiveDocument.Undo
'Restore original hidden text print configuration
Options.PrintHiddenText = bOpt
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what fkin G, thanks a lot fam <3